# Updating flash website, when does the browser download the new version

Tags: flash

This might be a simple question, but I'll ask it anyways. I know when I update my flash website I have to clear the cache to view the changes. Now, will all users have to do that to see the new changes, or will the browser eventually detect changes and download the new version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users will likely need to refresh their caches to see changes as well.

A little trick to get around this is to specify a unique value to a parameter when you embed the SWF, for example:

```
<embed src="media.swf?version=1.02" />
```

Where the value of `version` can be updated each upload.

Comment: can I just append that to my swf file, or is there some actionscript I must add? Also, I'm using SWFObject to embed. Does that change anything?

Comment: Not sure about SWFObject but there's no changes to the Flash file required. Just gotta add it on the end of the filename in the embed code.

Comment: This is a good solution. This is a simple query string value being added which won't cause any issues but is still seen as unique in the web browser. The tricky part is that the html may also be cached but that's usually not a big deal. There are ways to change the expiration on these items but it depends on the server-side technology available.